# Faster and cleaner SHA-1 leading zero histogram with Python

Tags: python, cryptography

I've written a python code for finding the distribution of the leading zeros of SHA-1. Using random inputs and hashing-then-counting. Normally it is expected to fit the `n/2^i` curve where `n` is the number of trials. After this, a plot is [drawn](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/83227/18298).

```py
import hashlib
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

leading = [0] * 160

trials = 10000000000

for i in range(trials):
    
    randomInput= random.getrandbits(128)
    
    hasvalue = hashlib.sha1(str(randomInput).encode('ASCII')).hexdigest()

    b = bin(int(hasvalue, 16))
    c= b[2:].zfill(160)
    zeroes = str(c).index('1')
    leading[zeroes] = leading[zeroes] + 1
```

The most time-consuming part of this code is of course the SHA-1 calculation and we cannot do something for that except parallelization with [pymp](https://github.com/classner/pymp) or some other library. What I'm not mostly unhappy here is the whole conversions between `str`, `bin` and back.

Any improvements for a cleaner code and little speed up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `str(random.getrandbits(128)).encode('ASCII')` I'd use `os.urandom(16)`. Much simpler, ought to be more random, shorter result, and a bit faster (at least for me). Or convert your random number to `bytes` directly, even faster (at least for me):

```
>>> timeit(lambda: str(random.getrandbits(128)).encode('ASCII'))
1.320366100000001
>>> timeit(lambda: os.urandom(16))
0.7796178000000111
>>> timeit(lambda: random.getrandbits(128).to_bytes(16, 'big'))
0.6476696999999945
```

From [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom):

> `os.urandom(size)`
> Return a string of *size* random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.

And to count zeros, perhaps use `digest()`, make an `int` from it and ask for its bit length:

```
    hashvalue = hashlib.sha1(os.urandom(16)).digest()
    i = int.from_bytes(hashvalue, 'big')
    zeroes = 160 - i.bit_length()
```

Benchmark results (numbers are times, so lower=faster):

```
0.56 zeroes_you
0.31 zeroes_me
0.29 zeroes_me2
0.26 zeroes_me3

0.60 zeroes_you
0.31 zeroes_me
0.28 zeroes_me2
0.24 zeroes_me3

0.57 zeroes_you
0.31 zeroes_me
0.28 zeroes_me2
0.24 zeroes_me3
```

Benchmark code:

```
import hashlib
import random
import os
from timeit import repeat

def zeroes_you():
    randomInput= random.getrandbits(128)
    hashvalue = hashlib.sha1(str(randomInput).encode('ASCII')).hexdigest()
    b = bin(int(hashvalue, 16))
    c= b[2:].zfill(160)
    zeroes = str(c).index('1')

def zeroes_me():
    hashvalue = hashlib.sha1(os.urandom(16)).digest()
    i = int.from_bytes(hashvalue, 'big')
    zeroes = 160 - i.bit_length()

def zeroes_me2():
    randomInput = random.getrandbits(128)
    hashvalue = hashlib.sha1(randomInput.to_bytes(16, 'big')).digest()
    i = int.from_bytes(hashvalue, 'big')
    zeroes = 160 - i.bit_length()
    
def zeroes_me3(randbits=random.getrandbits, sha1=hashlib.sha1, int_from_bytes=int.from_bytes):
    hashvalue = sha1(randbits(128).to_bytes(16, 'big')).digest()
    zeroes = 160 - int_from_bytes(hashvalue, 'big').bit_length()

for _ in range(3):
    for zeroes in zeroes_you, zeroes_me, zeroes_me2, zeroes_me3:
        t = min(repeat(zeroes, number=100000))
        print('%.2f' % t, zeroes.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: One issue might be it is blockable, in this case it make the run slower. I'll test. I'm not sure that my Ubuntu has run it in block mode or not. Here an article about it; [Removing the Linux /dev/random blocking pool](https://lwn.net/Articles/808575/)

Comment: As I predicted. The original code is faster. I suspect that this is due to the blocking. Run with 1000000 trials. The original one is around 2 times faster

Comment: @kelalaka I'm using Windows, `os.urandom` has always been faster for me. Note the answer update, maybe at least the second part is useful for you.

Comment: I think it is blocking here. `0.20 zeroes_you` and `0.34 zeroes_me` plus-minus 2 at most. with your second part, it falls to `0.13`. Nice and clean.

Comment: Now with the `zeroes_me2()` it is `0.10-0.12`. So I've 2 times speed up now :)

Comment: Now with the `zeroes_me3()` it is `0.09-0.10`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answer and yourself that you should try and keep away from encoding / decoding binary values altogether. The same goes for finding the highest bit from a number; converting to a string to find a character is vastly less performant than looking for bits directly. However, that's already mentioned [in the other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/247489/9555), so this is just code review following up on that.

I'm not sure why you would not just use `i` (formatted as a byte array) as input, I just wanted to mention that as the RNG might well be dependent on a hash, and may therefore be a bigger bottleneck than the SHA-1 hash itself. Just a small note that `getrandbits` uses the Mersenne Twister underneath, so you should get non-secure but well distributed random numbers from it (so *that* particular random number generator probably won't be a bottleneck).

Since Python 3.6 you can use underscores in number literals (`10_000_000_000` is easier to distinguish as 10 billion on the short scale). Otherwise you can write it down as `10 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000` which at least makes is readable without having to manually count zeros.

[EDIT] I've removed the part of `str` method adding additional characters (which it seemingly still does). For this question the encoding of the characters afterwards as ASCII seems to resolve the issue anyway. Encoding as a string and then converting back to bytes immediately after still doesn't seem to be the way to go, obviously.

Comment: `10**10` might  be good, too. Your paragraph about encodings doesn't make sense. In what way does `str` default to UTF-8? Do you mean `str.encode`? And that *doesn't* default to including BOM (`str(123).encode()` just gives me `b'123'`). And what do you mean with "binary values"? And `ascii` doesn't work, you probably mean `'ascii'`. And why ASCII? Gives the same result as UTF-8 (if it gives one at all). And the OP already *does* use ASCII, so why do you tell them?

Comment: It's the `str` function itself that adds the BOM as "characters". OK, you are right, directly encoding afterwards may again remove the BOM. However the intermediate string, if you will look at it, will be 3 chars / bytes larger because of the BOM. Of course, first converting to characters and then to bytes again makes little sense anyway.

Comment: That just sounds all wrong. How exactly do you show that difference of 3 bytes?

Comment: I ran into it [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63402380/589259)

Comment: About the edit: `str` doesn't add additional characters here. They're using it twice, once on an integer (producing a string of just digits and no additional characters) and once on a character string (returning that string itself, unmodified). Never on a byte string.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm not mostly unhappy here is the whole conversions between str, bin and back.

You can avoid this by first using `digest()` (instead of `hexdigest()`) to format the digest as bytes instead of a string, then converting the bytes directly to an integer:

```py
hasvalue = hashlib.sha1(random.getrandbits(128).to_bytes(16, byteorder='big', signed=False)).digest()
hasvalue = int.from_bytes(hasvalue, byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

Then you take the bitlength of that integer and subtract it from 160 (or whatever is the bitlength of the hash you're using) to get the number of leading zeroes:

```py
bitlength = 0
while (hasvalue):
    hasvalue >>= 1
    bitlength += 1
leading_zeros = 160-bitlength
```

Comment: This seems lost costlier, on average the while loop will run 159 times. Can you execute a performance as [superb rain](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/247489/185475) did?

Comment: Actually I didn't even realize Python had a built-in bit_length(). My way would definitely be slower than that.